# Generating Random values and Summing them to zero in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, random, for-loop

I have to generate a series of random numbers, say 100, within range of -1 and 1 and scale them by a value, say square root of 2. After which I take those 100 values and their sum = 0. Then scale that sum by another value. Check the code below to see what I mean.

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim sum As Double = 0
Dim kin As Double = 0

For j As Integer = 0 To 99
    rand.NextDouble()
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", (rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1) * Math.Sqrt(2))
    sum = sum + ((rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1) * Math.Sqrt(2))
    kin = kin + Math.Pow(sum, 2)
Next
Console.WriteLine(sum)
Console.WriteLine(kin)
```

I cannot get the sum to equal 0. The random distribution is supposed to be uniform so the summation would normally be 0 between (-1,1). Both sum and kin have 100 values.

Ultimately, I am trying to calculate the conservation of momentum.

Comment: `Just so you know the random distribution is supposed to be uniform so the summation would normally be 0 between`. It should be fairly close to zero, but never "zero every time". There are good changes that it would not be *exactly* zero.

Comment: In fact, the theoretical probability of it summing to 0 is... 0. Isn't math fun?

Comment: Also, you're generating 300 random numbers. Should you be placing the result of rand.NextDouble() into a variable?

Comment: My goal is to generate a sequence of uniform random numbers from -1 to 1 so that their sum is 0 or something close to it. However, I seem to be having trouble getting the "uniform" part. You can omit the math.sqrt(2) part for now and just consider the sum of random numbers between -1 and 1, however, it never is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

`NextDouble` should be giving you a uniform distribution.  That's not the same thing as saying that all acquired values will average to the mean.

Perhaps the actual problem you're seeing is that `kin` isn't being computed correctly.  For every iteration, you're adding `sum ^ 2`.  Squaring a negative will always yield a positive number, and you're compounding the result in `kin` besides.  If you weren't summing `kin`, and just calculated it *after* the loop, i.e. `kin = Math.Pow(sum, 2)`, then you'll see that `sum` *does* tend to 0.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you're not using your generated random numbers correctly and are duplicating calculations.  Here are the modifications I recommend:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim sum As Double = 0
Dim kin As Double = 0
Dim randomValue As Double

For j As Integer = 0 To 99
    randomValue = (rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1) * Math.Sqrt(2)
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", randomValue)
    sum = sum + randomValue
Next

kin = Math.Pow(sum, 2)

Console.WriteLine(sum)
Console.WriteLine(kin)
```